# OpenERP :Simple use of fields.function

Tags: python, odoo

I try to make some calculation of fields of my object and store them to a new field.
I'm beginning with a simple example of using fileds.function, but when I try to login to openerp, the system raise an error that the user or password is incorrect.

in my class I add the field:

```
      'a' : fields.integer('A'),
      'b' : fields.integer('B'),
      'total' : fields.function(fnct, method=True, string='Tot',type='integer'),
```

definition of the function:

```
       def fnct(self, cr, uid, ids, fields, arg, context):

          x = {}

          for record in self.browse(cr, uid, ids):

              x[record.id] = record.a + record.b

          return x
```

Please ,can anyone help me ? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no Connection of Function Filed with OpenERP Login.

So It may be possible that you are providing wrong user id or password.

**The Main Use of Function Field is:**

Auto Calculate Value of the field based on other Fields.

i.e Total = field1 + field2 + field3

Example:
     'total' : fields.function(get_total, method=True, string='Total',type='integer'),

**How to define Function:**

```
def get_total(self, cr, uid, ids, fields, arg, context):

    x={}

    for record in self.browse(cr, uid, ids):

        x[record.id]= record.field1 + record.field2 + record.field3

    return x
```

Comment: Thank you Avadhesh for your help.But I'm sure that user and pass are correct because when I comment the code with the function, I can login.I tried to calculate Value of the field based on other Fields as you said it still doesn't work!

Comment: Which Error you are getting ?

Comment: when I login i get "Mauvais nom d'utilisateur ou mot de passe" but i'm sure they are correct!! here is my new function              'def fnct(self, cr, uid, ids, fields, arg, context):
                                                                 x = {}
      for record in self.browse(cr, uid, ids):
           x[record.id] = record.a + record.b
   return x'

Comment: thank you very much I tried with new database So i could know what's the problems.

Answer (score 2):

To fix that issue, I check for some intendation and also the definition of my function should be before declaration of fields .

Comment: Congrats on the fix!  When you are able, please make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' so that others will be able to learn from your solution.  Cheers~

Answer (score 0):

```
def fnct(self, cr, uid, ids, fields, arg, context):

    x = {}

    for record in self.browse(cr, uid, ids):

    x[record.id] = record.a - record.b

if x[record.id]<0:

    raise osv.except_osv(("Warning"),("You Cant Subtract %s ")%(record.a - record.b))

else:


return x

    "a":fields.integer('A'),
    "b":fields.integer('B'),


 "total":fields.function(fnct, method=True, string='Total',type='integer'),
```